# jQuery Modal Confirmation Onload Open

Tags: jquery, html

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

I'm a little new to jQuery, so please bear with me. Having received some guidance from an earlier post, I've added the Modal Confirmation dialog to a gallery page as shown in the script below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
  <title>Gallery</title> 
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  <link href="Libraries/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
  <link href="Styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
  <!--[if IE]>   
  <link href="Styles/ie.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
  <![endif]-->
  <script src="Libraries/jquery/jquery-1.4.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
  <script src="Libraries/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>         
  <script type="text/javascript"> 

  $(function() { $('a.fancybox').fancybox(); }); 

  </script> 
  <style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 {
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-right: 110px;
}
.style4 {font-size: 12px}
-->
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function showdialog() {
        // a workaround for a flaw in the demo system (http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4375), ignore!
        $( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );

        $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height:160,
            modal: false,
            buttons: {
                "Delete image": function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });
    });
    </script>


</head>
<body style="font-family: Calibri; color:  #505050; font-size: 9px; border-bottom-width: thin; margin-top: 5px; margin-left: -476px; margin-right: 1px; margin-bottom: -10px;">
<div align="right" class="style1"> <a href = "javascript:document.gallery.submit()"/> Add Images <a/> &larr; View Uploaded Images </div>
  <form id="gallery" name="gallery" class="page" action="index.php" method="post">  
  <div id="container"> 
    <div id="center"> 
      <div class="aB"> 
        <div class="aB-B"> 
          <?php if ('Uploaded files' != $current['title']) :?>
          <?php endif;?>
          <input name="deleteimage" type="button" value="Delete Selected Image" onclick="showdialog()" />
          <div class="demo"> 
            <div class="inner"> 
              <div class="container"> 
                <div class="gallery"> 
                  <ul class="gallery-image-list"> 
                  <?php for ($i = 0; $i < $descriptions->documentElement->childNodes->length; $i++) : 
                          $xmlFile = $descriptions->documentElement->childNodes->item($i); 
                          $name = htmlentities($xmlFile->getAttribute('originalname'), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'); 
                          $description = htmlentities($xmlFile->getAttribute('description'), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'); 
                          $source = $galleryPath . rawurlencode($xmlFile->getAttribute('source')); 
                          $thumbnail = $thumbnailsPath . rawurlencode($xmlFile->getAttribute('thumbnail')); 
                  ?>
                    <li class="item"> 
                      <a class="fancybox" target="_blank" rel="original" href="<?php echo $source; ?>"><img class="preview" 
                        alt="<?php echo $name; ?>"  src="<?php echo $thumbnail; ?>" /></a><?php echo "<input type='radio' name='del' value='{$name}' />"?></li>
                        <p><span class="style4"><b>Image Name:</b> <?php echo htmlentities($xmlFile->getAttribute('originalname'));?> <br />
                          <b>Image Description:</b> <?php echo htmlentities($xmlFile->getAttribute('description'));?> </span><br />  
                          <?php endfor; ?>
                          </li>
                        </p>
                  </ul>
                </div> 
              </div> 
            </div> 

    </div> 
    <div id="dialog-confirm" title="Delete This Image?">
    <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>This image will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered. Are you sure?</p>
</div>
    </div> 
        <div class="aB-a">        </div> 
      </div> 
    </div> 
  </div> 
  </form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

The problem I'm having is that the dialog opens on page load, whereas I would like it to only
appear on a button click. I've got the dialog box to open on the button click, but I can't find anyway of stopping it opening on page load.

I've looked through the jQuery documenation and there's nothing that I can see that gives you the option of changing this setting.

I just wondered whether someone may be able to look at this please and let me know where I'm going wrong?

Many thanks and regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `$` from your function declaration. You don't need to use jQuery to define a regular function.

```
$(function showdialog() { ... });
```

should be

```
function showdialog() { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the class "hide" to the css and to the div dialog (like this):

```
.hide{
  display: none !important; 
 }


 <div id="dialog-confirm" class="hide" title="Delete This Image?">
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for taking the time to reply with an alternative solution. I'll keep this for later use. Kind regards